# Hyperbolic PDE with Flux Singularity

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider the system of balance laws
$$\partial_t u+\partial_x F_{\epsilon}(u) = S (u),$$
where $u = u(x,t) \in R^n$ denotes the state vector,  $F: R^n \to R^n$ is the flux and $S:R^n \to R^n$ some source term. Let $A_{\epsilon} = DF_{\epsilon}$ denote the flux Jacobian matrix. We assume that $A_{\epsilon}$ has $n$ real and pair-wise distinct eigenvalues for all $u \in R^n$ and $\epsilon >0$, such that the above PDE is strictly hyperbolic. In the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, some of the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k$ of $A_{\epsilon}$ diverge on the subspace $T \in R^n$, while the remaining eigenvalues converge to finite values.

Let $u_{\epsilon}$ denote the solution to the above balance law for some $\epsilon >0$. I'm interested in the characterization of the limit of solutions $u_{\epsilon_1}, u_{\epsilon_2}, u_{\epsilon_3}, \ldots$ with $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2 > \epsilon_3 > \ldots$

I'd be very much interested in literature, where this kind of problem has been considered.

Best regards,
Roman